# iOS - how to add action in new line in UIAlertConroller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I need to add action in new line just like: [alertActionsWithNewLines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dnv6.png)

I'm trying this code:

```
let uncheckInAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to uncheck-in?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    uncheckInAlert.setTitleImage(UIImage(named: "fail_Icon"))
    uncheckInAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.userUncheckIn()
    }))
    uncheckInAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(uncheckInAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But as result I have something like: [alertActionsInOneLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhfDW.png).
If action title is large then action automatically carried over on new line. With small action title, actions is grouped in one line. Is there any a ways to do this?

Comment: Try adding a bunch of spaces to the title: `"    Yes    "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no flag you can set in order to change how Apple lays out its alert buttons. The `UIAlertController` with style `alert` will, however, change it's button layout automatically to vertical when it cannot properly fit the entire string of the button's text in a horizontal layout. So if your button's text is long enough, it will change the layout.

Though this is a solution to your question, I don't recommend adding arbitrary spaces or unnecessarily long strings to the button's text just so Apple will layout the buttons vertically in a production app. It's misusing the standard components and could easily start breaking down once strings become localized to other languages. In order to naturally achieve the desired behavior I would suggest creating your own, custom view to display buttons vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Changing these lines from

```
uncheckInAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
```

To

```
uncheckInAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
```

---

```
let uncheckInAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to uncheck-in?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

To

```
let uncheckInAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to uncheck-in?", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
```

This will show `cancel` option grouped with other options.

Comment: If you use an action sheet, be sure to include the following for iPads (or it will crash): `uncheckInAlert.popoverPresentationController?.barBottonItem = theButtonThatTriggeredTheAlert`.  This will anchor the popover to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try change style form .alert to .actionSheet

Like in this code

```
let uncheckInAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to uncheck-in?", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
```

Comment: I tried this. But this style a bit different from design that I need. Thanks